# Engine and App have same class name - can't add attributes to App's class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm developing an engine to be used within a number of other applications. It provides some core `Player` and `Action` functionality for apps using gamification concepts.

The engine has a `Player` model with basic attributes and methods, which I've tested separately (with RSpec) and everything is working on its own. I'm integrating the engine with another app and all the default functionality is ok, but when I try to extend the *App's* `Player` model with additional attributes they make it to the db, but aren't accessible from the Ruby class. 
My suspicion is that the issue is related to the fact that the `Player` classes have the same name and that the App's class inherits from the Engine's class, but I can't figure out the exact problem and how to fix it.
Explanation/code follows:

### Engine files

**Engine's Player class:**

```
module CoreEngine
  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, class_name: CoreEngine.user_class
    has_many :player_actions

    def add_action(some_action)
      self.player_actions.create(action: some_action)
    end

    def add_actions(array_of_actions)
      array_of_actions.each do |action|
        self.add_action(action)
      end
    end

    def total_score
      self.player_actions.sum(:points_earned)
    end
  end
end
```

**Engine's Player Schema:**

```
create_table "core_engine_players", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

**lib/core_engine/engine.rb**

```
module CoreEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace CoreEngine

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework      :rspec,        :fixture => false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
      g.assets false
      g.helper false
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/core_engine.rb**

```
require "core_engine/engine"

module CoreEngine
  mattr_accessor :player_class
  mattr_accessor :action_class
  mattr_accessor :user_class

  def self.root
    File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
  end

  def self.models_dir
    "#{root}/app/models/core_engine/"
  end

  def self.controllers_dir
    "#{root}/app/controllers/core_engine/"
  end
end
```

---

## App files

**config/initializers/core_engine.rb**

```
CoreEngine.player_class = "Player"
```

I've included the core_engine gem properly (not shown here)

**App's Player class (notice it is inheriting from the engine):**

```
class Player < CoreEngine::Player
end
```

**App's Player schema**

```
  create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "energy"
    t.integer  "credits"
  end
```

Notice above that `energy` and `credits` are present. I've also verified that they are in the actual Postgres table via `psql`:

```
                                     Table "public.players"
   Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 user_id    | integer                     | 
 energy     | integer                     | 
 credits    | integer                     | 
Indexes:
    "players_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I don't get any migration errors. Nevertheless, when I run a rails console and call `Player` I get:

```
2.1.1p76 :001 > Player
 => Player(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string, user_id: integer)
```

No `energy` to be found anywhere. I'm sure it has to do with inheriting from the engine's `Player` model, but I don't see what the actual problem is. I'm able to define methods in the App's `Player` model that it can call, as well as methods in the Engine's `Player` model that *both* can call, but not attributes like this.

I suppose I could potentially use explicit methods to access those definitely-existing database columns, but I'd prefer it if I could just use Rails/ActiveRecord as usual.

This is my first experience with engines (first post, too!) and everything has been very positive up until now. Any help will be **greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be, a Player model points to engine table. Check it within Rails console by `Player.table_name`. If it's `core_engine_players`, simply override it within app Player class

```html
class Player
  self.table_name = 'players'
end
```

Comment: Hah, That's totally it! Thanks!!

Comment: ...then again, if I do this I don't have access to the database tables that come in with the engine (for instance, `name` is a `CoreEngine::Player` attribute that I lose if I set the `table_name` to the App's table. Perhaps that's an indication that I am going about this the wrong way to begin with. 
Any ideas on that?

Comment: In short, you cannot use two tables for one model (or actually you can, but it needs table name switching which would be annoying). If you want to decorate player model with extra fields, consider adding an association within your app.

Comment: For getting decorator-like functionality via an engine, does this seem appropriate: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers  ?

Comment: In this case engine model extends main app model with some logic. In your case however, that's not the point. With engine you want to provide some model and then extend it within main app. You may indeed extend its logic as stated in the link you've provided, however you cannot deal with database in a such way. Think about it  that you've a base Player model provided by engine and in main app you have some other model, let's call it BetterPlayer, which `belongs_to Player` (via an association) and Player `has_one BetterPlayer`.